# Send a Video from an Android Phone to Google Chromecast Dongle Programmatically

Tags: android, video-streaming, chromecast

I'm aware that this question is broad but I would like to know how can I send a video from an Android Phone to Google Chromecast Dongle Programmatically.
I'm not asking for the code, just links, tutorials, how-to's.
Tks.

Comment: Is the video stored on the phone? Or are you asking to play back a video for which the phone knows the URL?

Comment: @CommonsWare Let's assume the video is ONLINE and I've the URL.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am able to play video from URL( as given in sample) But How to play the video if it is in device ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either [use `RemotePlaybackClient`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#remote-playback) (though there appear to be bugs here), or use [the Cast SDK](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/cast.html), with or without [the Cast Companion Library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android).

[Here is a sample app for the `RemotePlaybackClient` option](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaRouter/RemotePlayback), with some workarounds for the bugs. With luck, I will be able to remove some of those workarounds in the future.

Comment: There is a number of sample apps on our GitHub repo for doing that: https://github.com/googlecast

Comment: @CommonsWare your app for the RemotePlaybackClient, works as expected! tks

Comment: @MartinDeSimone: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sorry, the example you provided, it is still working?

Comment: @MartinDeSimone: It worked the last time that I tried it (subject to known bugs), but that has been a while.

Comment: Works awesome, the only thing that i had to change was the onAttach of the fragment, since it has been deprecated